# codeigniter $this->output->set_content_type('application/json') causing 500 error

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

This is the code snippet i am using to output json from my api built using `CodeIgniter 2.1.4`.

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
     ->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

`$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')` is throwing 500 error. if I remove it in case of json it works (doesn't throw 500).

I use the same snippet to output image and it works. But it doesn't work with json.

Comment: Check your PHP error log or turn on displaying of errors - PHP will then tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I did but the error logs doesn't show this error. In any way I am using `header('Content-Type: application/json');` for json instead of codeigniter output class function. Maybe it has something to do with codeigniter sending headers too early or something.